# flutter and problems with FocusNode

Tags: flutter

When I load my code it works and compiles, but when I restart the application it starts but stays on a white screen and Flutter shows me the following code:

```
void _markNeedsUpdate() {
       assert(_focusDebug(() => 'Schedule update, current focus is $_primaryFocus, next focus will be $_markedForFocus'));
       if (_haveScheduledUpdate) {
         return;
       }
       _haveScheduledUpdate = true;
       scheduleMicrotask(_applyFocusChange);
}
```

and I don't know what the error could be, also it only happens when an event is added
this is my current code

```
import 'package:calendar_demo/app/App.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

import 'package:calendar_demo/app/view/MyHomePage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

DateTime _today = DateTime.now();
late Map<DateTime, List<Map<String, String>>> _events;
late List<Map<String, String>> _selectedEvent;
late TextEditingController _controller;
TimeOfDay? time = TimeOfDay(hour: 12, minute: 12);
String _timecontroller = "";
late SharedPreferences prefs;

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _events = {};
    _timecontroller = time.toString();
    _controller = TextEditingController();
    _selectedEvent = [];
    initPrefs();
  }

  initPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _events = Map<DateTime, List<Map<String, String>>>.from(decodeMap(json.decode(prefs.getString("events") ?? "{}")));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text("Calendar Demo"),
      ),
      body:  _Calendar(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          showAddDialog(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  showAddDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        content: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _controller,
            ),
            Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Text(
                  '${time!.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${time!.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
                );
              },
            ),
            /*FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                TimeOfDay? newTime = await showTimePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialTime: time!,
                );
                setState(() {
                  if (newTime != null) {
                    time = newTime;
                    _timecontroller = newTime.format(context);
                    print(_timecontroller);
                  }
                });
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.access_time_outlined),
            )*/
          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Text("Save"),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_controller.text.isEmpty) return;
              setState(() {
                final Map<String, String> newEvent = {
                  'title': _controller.text,
                  'time': _timecontroller,
                };

                if (_events[_today] != null) {
                  _events[_today]?.add(newEvent);
                } else {
                  _events[_today] = [newEvent];
                }

                prefs.setString("events", json.encode(encodeMap(_events)));
                Navigator.pop(context);
                getEventsForDay(_today);
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Calendar extends StatefulWidget {
  _Calendar({super.key});

  @override
  State<_Calendar> createState() => _CalendarState();
}

class _CalendarState extends State<_Calendar> {
  void _onDaySelected(DateTime day, DateTime focusedDay) {
    setState(() {
      _today = day;
      _selectedEvent = getEventsForDay(day);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text("Selected day= ${_today.toString().split(" ")[0]}"),
          Text(_timecontroller),
          TableCalendar(
            focusedDay: _today,
            locale: "en_US",
            eventLoader: getEventsForDay,
            rowHeight: 43,
            headerStyle: const HeaderStyle(formatButtonVisible: false),
            availableGestures: AvailableGestures.all,
            selectedDayPredicate: (day) => isSameDay(day, _today),
            onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
            firstDay: DateTime.utc(2023, 10, 16),
            lastDay: DateTime.utc(2033, 3, 14),
          ),
          ..._selectedEvent.map((event) => ListTile(
            title: Text('${event['title']} - ${event['time']}'),
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<Map<String, String>> getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
  return _events[day] ?? [];
}

Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> encodeMap(Map<DateTime, dynamic> map) {
  Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> newMap = {};
  map.forEach((key, value) {
    newMap[key.toString()] = List<Map<String, String>>.from(map[key]);
  });
  return newMap;
}

Map<DateTime, List<Map<String, String>>> decodeMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  Map<DateTime, List<Map<String, String>>> newMap = {};
  map.forEach((key, value) {
    newMap[DateTime.parse(key)] = List<Map<String, String>>.from(map[key]);
  });
  return newMap;
}
```

I have tried commenting on various parts of the code and even doing it again from scratch. What I want to achieve is that the events can be added and when restarting the app the saved events are not deleted but rather persist.